# Null pointer exception during initialization of an object

Tags: exception

```
List<Products2> product = [select....];
if (product != null) {
   Quote_Line_Item__c qli = new Quote_Line_Item__c();
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception inside IF condition.
FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.

Comment: what is product?

Comment: Its a list of Products
Products2 product = select { SOQL query here which is returning values}

Comment: @user3303348 - I cannot replicate this issue at all with the above code. Can you be so kind as to also append the relevant portion of the debug logs and indicate in your code above the line numbers the code lines represent at the time of the debug log generation. Maybe you have found a bug on your instance, maybe you are reading the logs wrong, looking at the wrong code, who knows. But as it is posted, the error cannot be replicated on my end. Also you say on initialization of an object and that would not be the `product != null` line. Something is not matching up.....

Comment: I would expect the error to be attempt to de-reference a null object instead of null pointer exception for the given code..

Comment: @javanoob - How would you expect that error or NPE to be thrown?? There is no dereferencing.  if the OP had used `!product == null` then it would DNO but that is not what the OP is doing

Comment: @Eric, I was wrong..sorry for creating confusion. Looks like DNO and NPE both are same and would be thrown only when we try to invoke a method or refercing a property of the null object.

Comment: @javanoob -All good, this question though is really frustrating as I do not see how it could occur yet we have an answer from someone who I would never question and believe to be true but the issue cannot be reproduced....

Comment: As written in the question, with a query into a list, the list will never be null. SOQL will always return an empty list if there are no results. There is other code not shown in the question which is causing this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means the value of `product` IS null and thus failed your If condition. You got a null pointer exception when it failed. You'll need to nest your test inside of a try-catch block to prevent this from happening.

**Edit**

Further explanation:

Had you used `If(!product.isEmpty())` or `If(product.isEmpty() = false)`, you'd not have had any problems. You could have done a similar kind of thing using `product.size()`.

Because `list<Product2> product` was initialized as a query, in order to determine if it was null, Apex had to look for a `recordId` as in `product[0].Id`. When it tried to do that, it couldn't make the assignment from the query results to `product`. That's what caused the nullPointerException to be thrown.

**Edit2:**

I did some additional testing myself and could not reproduce the OP's error with a query that returned zero results. Unless it was a nested query, there would be a query exception with a query that returned zero result.

Yet, the error message posted clearly indicates the variable `product` could not be assigned a value due to a NPE. I can only conclude that it came from some earlier portion of his code; perhaps from outside of a `for` loop his code may have been nested within at the time his error was reported, or as the results of a subquery that couldn't be assigned.

Below is an example of what I'm speaking of. I've made relevant comments in the code that are important to note:

```
MAP<ID, Opportunity>OppMap = New Map<ID, Opportunity>([Select Id, Name, Amount, CloseDate, StageName, SyncedQuoteID, 
   (SELECT ID, Description, Name, OpportunityId, PricebookEntryId, Product2Id, ProductCode, Quantity, UnitPrice, TotalPrice 
   FROM OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity Where Name =: 'TEST']);

For(Id OppId : OppMap.Keyset()){

list<OpportunityLineItem>OLI = OppMap.get(OppId).OpportunityLineItems;

    For(OpportunityLineItem o : OLI){
    // Note: if OLI isEmpty(), then no iteration occurs to cause the following line 
    // to execute for testing, so couldn't confirm expected behavior with data on hand.
    // Further, note that adding null Ids to a list won't cause the If statement to throw an exception

       if(o.Product2ID != null){
           QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem();
       }

    }
}
```

Of further interest, note that the following code will throw a null pointer exception at the system.debug statement, but **not** at the `if` statement when the debug statement is commented out:

```
list<Product2>product = new list<Product2>();

product = [select Id, Name from Product2 limit 1];

system.debug('size = '  + product.size() );

product = null;

system.debug(  product.size() );

    if(product != null){
       QuoteLineItem qli = new QuoteLineItem();
    }
```

Comment: If I am reading the OP question, as it is posted (code) it should not throw a NPE at anytime...Correct?

Comment: you are right sir. I was not expecting it to throw the exception there.

Comment: @Eric If the argument cannot be null, then the exception occurred when the `If` statement tried to check for the value assigned to the variable named `product`. That's when the null pointer exception occurred. So, no the code in his post could throw the exception if it was a separate line nested within a try statement.

Comment: @crmprogdev but `If(product != null)` cannot throw a NPE  and there is no use of product within the if block  I am confused as to where you are going. Maybe I just need a drink....Product != null will not throw a NPE if product is null??? Again maybe I need a drink...

Comment: @Eric, because of the way Apex had to go look for the assignment of product in this particular case, it couldn't make the assignment from one list to another and thus a null pointer exception was generated. Notice in his later comments that he tells us product is the result of a query assignment. It's not a list or a single variable that he initialized by some other means.

Comment: @crmprogdev - Bear with me....I want to understand. this code works fine `Product2 product;

if(product != null)
    system.debug('here');
` so can you add to your answer code to replicate the issue. I am not sure why I am not getting this but it has to be some unique way in which the OP is writing the code as you say. Is it something you can whip up in your answer to replicate? (good catch BTW)

Comment: See my Edited answer for further enlightenment on why this occurred.

Comment: Thanks but I guess I will just have to accept that it is true. I tried to replicate what you have said but I still do not get a NPE: `Product2[] product = [Select ID From Product2 where ID = null];

if(product != null)
    system.debug('here');
` Removing the where clause does not change the outcome either - Again, thanks for keeping with this. I am not sure the OP has this resolved by the comment on the other answer telling him to do what you suggested...

Comment: @crmprogdev - I highly respect your answers and comments (and believe them to be true) and I am not trying to be difficult.....

Comment: He really needs to be check for `isEmpty`, not `!= null`. I wrote my initial answer before he posted that he'd initialized it with a query totally based on the error message which was saying that it couldn't assign the value to product. Exactly what the source of `product` is, isn't entirely clear is it? One normally wouldn't test a list against null.

Comment: @crmprogdev - agreed, depending on the code. `Product2[] product; if(product.isEmpty())` would produce a NPE so it depends on the order of execution. This is all conjecture and I do not think we have a clear picture so......As it stands, respectfully, I still cannot see how `if(VAR != null)` would ever throw a NPE...Thank you for taking the time to indulge...

Comment: I agree with eric's point here..Even I tried the same code several ways but could not reproduce the null pointer exception.. I guess OP did not share complete details for this problem.

Comment: I'm in the same boat, I believe the query would return an empty list which would not cause a null pointer exception when you test whether it is equal to null. Although why you would test it for null, given that it can never be null, is a question which hints at a different problem with the code.

Comment: Please note my latest edits above with code I've tested in the dev console and my comments on it.

Comment: @crmprogdev - Thank you for the time you spent on this and confirming what I was thinking / saying....All of your efforts are greatly appreciated and this is a great thread for someone facing the NPE exception issue...I am voting to close the question unless there is further clarification from the OP with debug logs proving that the code posted is what is actually throwing the NPE. as it stands we do not have reproducible error in the question

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone who have helped me. I found that the Quote line item did not have the access to all the users. Strange thing. Once I gave the access, this issue has been resolved.

@crmprogdev-- thank you very much for explaining so clearly. It will definitely help me and lot of people.

Comment: Still does not make sense. There has to be other code at work here.

Comment: Hi Eric-- I did not add any code other than access thing. It worked. Really strange. I went through the same thing, you are going through. But thats all I can say. I granted the access, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try {
    if(product != null) {
    Quote_Line_Item__c qli = new Quote_Line_Item__c(); 
   }
  } catch(Exception e) {
  System.debug('The following exception has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: It is inside a try block. I pasted the same error message I received

Comment: @user3303348 - If it was inside a try catch block then you would not have received an NPE error. Can you update with the rest of the related code? This answer is what crmprogdev is telling you to do....